# How to disable the second click on a button

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6, ecmascript-5, html-framework-7

I have a button that opens a modal in `framework7`, however the modal opens twice if double clicked, I'm trying to not allow double clicks on that  button with no luck.

```
$(Button, {
  fill: true,
  raised: true,
  noFastClick: true,
  onClick: this.handle_click
})

const clickTimes: any[] = []

handle_click = (button) => {
   const clickTime = new Date().getTime()
   clickTimes.push(clickTime)
   if (clickTimes.length > 1) {
       console.log("double click detected")
       button.disabled = true
       clickTimes.length = 0
       return
   }
}
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Check if the modal is already rendered on not inside the event handler. Or remove the event handler on click and readd it on closing the modal. Or just use a debounce function, like you're trying to write yourself. https://davidwalsh.name/javascript-debounce-function

Answer (score 0):

You can check that the event's `detail` property is `1`, meaning it's not the second click of a double click.

```js
If (e.detail !== 1) { return }
```

or use something like `lodash`'s [`throttle`](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.11#throttle)

```js
handle_click = _.throttle(func, 500)
```

Which will ensure the function can be called a most one time per `500ms`

Comment: it still fires 2 mouse click events both with detail: 1

Comment: You might need to use `throttle` then

Comment: how should I use the handler? does it go inside the handle_click function?

Comment: Let me specify. It is the handle_click function

Answer (score 0):

Since, you are already recording number of clicks.
How about you disable the button when the modal is opened and enable it once the modal is closed?

```
return <button
  type='button'
  className={
    this.state.isModalActive ? 'disable' : ''
  }
  onClick={ this.handleClick }
>
```

Make sure you update the state ***isModalActive*** on each interaction with the button.